# Using Sum() or something similar with CalculateField_management and FieldLists

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-desktop, field-calculator

I need some help with using variables with CalculateField_management tool. I've tried several different scenarios but don't seem to have any luck.

What I have is a list of fields containing water consumption data for various months.

In my tables I have fields with the following field names: [JUN_12], [JUL_12], [AUG_12], etc... Each table spans 2 years June 2012 - May 2013, the next table will go from June 2013 - May 2014, etc...

These tables are actually views that resides in our billing system. Eventually, I will have another table that will have [JUN_13], [JUL_13] (incremented a year).

I'm trying to avoid hard coding each column name in my code to make it easier to update the code once a year. As these tables are created throughout the years, I'd like to only have to update the yr1 and yr2 parameters and have the script run. This should be the only change from one year / table to the next...

I am fairly new to python and appreciate any help that I can get.

Here's an example of what I have:

```py
#Variables...
yr1 = "08"
yr2 = "09"

sep = "_"

y1 = sep + yr1
y2 = sep + yr2

m1 = "JAN"
m2 = "FEB"
m3 = "MAR"
m4 = "APR"
m5 = "MAY"
m6 = "JUN"
m7 = "JUL"
m8 = "AUG"
m9 = "SEP"
m10 = "OCT"
m11 = "NOV"
m12 = "DEC"

fclass = EnergyGDB + "\\" + PZSPJoin
f1 = [str(f.name) for f in arcpy.ListFields(fclass, "{0}{1}".format(m6,y1))][0]
f2 = [str(f.name) for f in arcpy.ListFields(fclass, "{0}{1}".format(m7,y1))][0]
f3 = [str(f.name) for f in arcpy.ListFields(fclass, "{0}{1}".format(m8,y1))][0]
f4 = [str(f.name) for f in arcpy.ListFields(fclass, "{0}{1}".format(m9,y1))][0]
f5 = [str(f.name) for f in arcpy.ListFields(fclass, "{0}{1}".format(m10,y1))][0]
f6 = [str(f.name) for f in arcpy.ListFields(fclass, "{0}{1}".format(m11,y1))][0]
f7 = [str(f.name) for f in arcpy.ListFields(fclass, "{0}{1}".format(m12,y1))][0]
f8 = [str(f.name) for f in arcpy.ListFields(fclass, "{0}{1}".format(m1,y2))][0]
f9 = [str(f.name) for f in arcpy.ListFields(fclass, "{0}{1}".format(m2,y2))][0]
f10 = [str(f.name) for f in arcpy.ListFields(fclass, "{0}{1}".format(m3,y2))][0]
f11 = [str(f.name) for f in arcpy.ListFields(fclass, "{0}{1}".format(m4,y2))][0]
f12 = [str(f.name) for f in arcpy.ListFields(fclass, "{0}{1}".format(m5,y2))][0]

fieldList = [f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9, f10, f11, f12]
fields = ",".join("!{0}!".format(x) for x in fieldList)

#Calculation:
arcpy.CalculateField_management(PZSPJoin, "TotalCCF", "sum([{0}])".format(fields), "PYTHON", "")
```

There are a few other things that are happening in between the calculation and the variables, however this is where I'm having the issue. I'm trying to add all of the fields and have a total in a new field.

If I replace the variables with the actual field names, the script works just fine; but as soon as I introduce variables, it breaks.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using VB as your parser for Calculate field, the field names must be enclosed in brackets []. (For Python as the parser, field names are enclosed in exclamation points !!) See the help for [Calculate Field](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Calculate_Field/00170000004m000000/).

So, in your example, an easy way to code it would be thus, using str.format():

```py
arcpy.CalculateField_management(table, "field", 
                        "[{0}] + [{1}] + [{2}]".format(field1, field2, field3), "VB", "")
```

This can become a bit unwieldy when you are summing up a lot of fields, so the following is a good alternative:

```py
fieldlist = [field, field2, field3, etc.]
fields = ",".join("!{0}!".format(x) for x in fieldlist)

arcpy.CalculateField_management(table, "field", 
                                "sum([{0}])".format(fields), "PYTHON", "")
```

The same can be applied to your ListFields() to make that a bit simpler (and easier to understand in my opinion). You need to cast to string since ListFields() returns unicode. If you are only returning one field at a time, adding [0] (which just accesses the first item in the list) will return a string:

```py
field1 = [str(f.name) for f in arcpy.ListFields(fclass, "*{0}_{1}*".format(m1,yr1))][0]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Paul. I've attempted to apply your recommendations, but am still experiencing an error. In the CalculateField section, I'm getting a Invalid field [] error.

Comment: @EugeneDurshpek Can you edit your OP to reflect the new code?

Comment: @EugeneDurshpek, when the response doesn't fit in a comment (e.g. because you need code formatting) the convention is to amend (edit) the question instead of the other person's answer. Another approach is to leave a comment and link to a chat room created for exploring the Q (and then summarize the results of that chat back here later).

Comment: ...like here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9871/using-sum-or-something-similar-with-calculatefield-management-and-fieldlists

Comment: @Paul I'm unable to chat in the chat room. It's telling me that I must have a reputation of at lease 20 to talk there. I'm new to this site; as you can tell. I thought that I edited the original post, but must have done it wrong. Paul, I added arcpy.AddMessage(fields) as you mentioned in the chat, and came up with None as the result.

Comment: It's fine. Are you running this as a script or from within the python window in ArcMap?

Comment: I'm running it as a script. I'm using PyScripter. It appears that the issue may be with how I define each field. f1 = [f.name... When I try printing f1 (field1) it just gives me brackets [].

Comment: @EugeneDurshpek it's not grabbing the name of the field then. There could be an issue with the wildcard.

Comment: @Paul, you're absolutely right. I had an issue with the wildcard. I accidentally added an extra "_". I'm onto the next error. That is; when I list my fields, they come up like this: [u'JUN_08']. This gives me an invalid field error. My field should look like this: [JUN_08]. How do I get rid of the u that the ListFields function adds?

Comment: @EugeneDurshpek, I've edited the end of my post to fix that. It's a simple cast to str().

Comment: @Paul, sorry to take up so much of your time. I have added the str() cast to my code and am still getting an invalid field ['JUN_08'] message. The "u" went away when I added str() to the code. Could the single quotes be causing the issue?

Comment: @EugeneDurshpek I enjoy it. If you are only returning one field at a time, then you can append access it by index. Edited post.

Comment: @Paul, I'm not sure if I'm following your last comment. I've updated my code in the original post to reflect what the changes that you've helped with. In my arcpy.CalculateField_management function, I'm trying to sum f1 through f12 into my TotalCCF field. I'm not sure what you mean by returning one field at a time. For each row in my table, I want the sum of all fields that are defined.

Comment: @EugeneDurshpek When you use listfields inside of the brackets, it is not returning a string, it's returning a list. You can use `[0]` after that to extract the string from the list. Everything else should be the same.

Comment: @Paul, I still can't seem to get it to work. When you say that I can use [0] to extract the string from the list; are you talking about using [0] with the CalculateField expression? I replaced the {0} in my expression --> "sum([{0}])".format... with [0] and the process ran with no errors; however, that resulted in all rows getting a value of 0 as opposed to a sum of all fields. I don't know if this helps; all of the fields that I'm using are formatted as double in the database.

Comment: @Paul, I finally got it. Thank you for all of your help on this. I have updated the code in this post to reflect the successful code. I really appreciate you helping me with this.

Comment: @EugeneDurshpek, glad it finally worked!

Comment: @EugeneDurshpek I recommend that you thank Paul by upvoting his Answer and then clicking on the green tick to Accept it as well.